# Does this sentence sound natural and correct?

Tags: meaning

There is a moon on a girl's T-shirt. So can I say the sentence below?

"**A girl is wearing a T-shirt with a moon**"?

Does this sentence convey the idea and sound natural?

Thank you so much <3

Comment: Yes, native speakers would know what you mean if you said this and will say sentences like it. A more formal way to say it would be "A girl is wearing a t-shirt with a moon on it." But your version is the common, slightly less formal way to say the same thing.

Comment: Or 'the Moon' since you presumably mean 'our' moon and not one of the moons of Jupiter, for example!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if someone is a wearing a T-shirt with a picture or item on it, you can say with a [noun].

For example.
With a moon, with a puppy, with a pretty tree.

We would often add: *on it* at the end.

A girl is wearing a T-shirt with a moon on it.